# rerunning the same command with different parameters

Tags: linux, parameters

hello I'm a beginner for linux. This is the command I want to run with different parameters:

```
'$GEM5/build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir="Outputs" hw4config.py -c $GEM5/../test_progs/daxpy/daxpy_arm_big --cpu-type="DerivO3CPU" --caches --#l2cache --num_phys_float_regs=phys --num_rob_entries=rob --num_iq_entries=iq'
```

And I want the parameters 'phys', 'rob' and 'iq' to change with a squared step size.
This my python script:

```
import os
phys = 256
rob = 4
iq = 4
i = 1
while phys <= 4096:
    rob = 4
    while rob <= 256:
     iq = 4
     while iq <= 256:
         cmd = '$GEM5/build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir="Outputs" hw4config.py -c $GEM5/../test_progs/daxpy/daxpy_arm_big --cpu-type="DerivO3CPU" --caches --#l2cache --num_phys_float_regs=phys --num_rob_entries=rob --num_iq_entries=iq'
         os.system(cmd)
         iq *= 2
         i += 1
     rob *= 2
    phys *= 2
```

When I run this python file in Terminal, There's an `invalid integer value 'phys'` error.
Then I change those 'phys', 'rob' ,'iq' parameters in the command line above into numbers directly, there's no error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: check your command - you have put the literals "phys", "iq" and "rob" there, and not their actual values. For example, `--num_rob_entries=rob` should be  replaced by  `--num_rob_entries=',rob,'`. The same replacements should be made for the other two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm...
How do you think Python can devise what you have in mind?

In your `cmd = ...` statement there's *no* substitution.

If Your Python is recent enough (3.5+) you can use a very similar line:

```
cmd = f'$GEM5/build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir="Outputs" hw4config.py -c $GEM5/../test_progs/daxpy/daxpy_arm_big --cpu-type="DerivO3CPU" --caches --#l2cache --num_phys_float_regs={phys} --num_rob_entries={rob} --num_iq_entries={iq}'
```

otherwise you'll need to resort to other formatting methods.

Your line, as-is, will try to feed a "--num_phys_float_regs=phys" (literally) parameter and your program rightly complains "phys" is not an integer value.

Comment: Thank u! The problem has been solved by your method!

Comment: @Sukey: if problem was solved then you should accept the answer.